# Pixi.js - How to animate a line

Tags: pixi.js

I've been looking everywhere but I can't find a way to animate a line in Pixi.js.

Given this code:

```
var line = new PIXI.Graphics();
line.lineStyle(1, 0xff0000);
line.moveTo(0,window.innerHeight/2);
line.lineTo(window.innerWidth/2, 0);
line.lineTo(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight/2);
app.stage.addChild(line);
```

which draws this magnificient [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv7f1z2g/)

I'd like to achieve this very simple line animation:

Step 1

[image: step 1]

Step 2

[image]

Of course I'm guessing this should not be complicated, but I've no idea what I'm missing...
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing inside a graphics object is very similar in API terms to drawing to a Canvas without Pixi.

A render loop is needed where the canvas is cleared and redrawn on every loop.
Pixi provides a useful Ticker that can be used to run functions on a loop.

Here's an example (in this case an infinite animation) and a [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ondkrc71/):

```
var line = new PIXI.Graphics(),
  centerY = 0,
  increment = 2;

app.stage.addChild(line);   

app.ticker.add(() => {
  // clear the graphics object ('wipe the blackboard')
  line.clear(); 

   // redraw a new line
  drawLine(centerY);

  // calculate the next position
  centerY = (centerY < window.innerHeight) ? centerY = centerY + increment : 0; 
});

function drawLine(centerY) {
    line.lineStyle(1, 0xff0000);
    line.moveTo(0,window.innerHeight/2);
    line.lineTo(window.innerWidth/2, centerY);
    line.lineTo(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight/2);
}
```